# VSTS extension for adding a textbox to workitem

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to add a textbox through the extension to VSTS. I need to know How to add a textbox using an extension to a work item in VSTS?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the sample below to custom work item control: [vsts-extension-multivalue-control](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-multivalue-control)

Answer (score 0):

Process to add new field/text box to workItem explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/customize-process#start-customizing)

1. Select a Work item and click on Action tab/menu and choose Customize Option[image: Customize option]
2. If the team project already uses an inherited process, then the Layout page for the corresponding WorkItem will open. Select New Field in Layout tab [image]
3. Provide New Field details [Name & type] as per your requirement. [image]